# Is there a formula for the number of ways an $N\times N$ grid can be filled with squares?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

How many ways are there to fill an $n\times n$ board with squares with varying sizes?

Comment: you want it completely filled right?

Comment: the board, that is ....

Comment: Interesting problem, did you have any preliminary thoughts or results?

Comment: Yes, meaning, there are no rectangular shapes left.

Comment: have you tried OEIS?

Comment: @Joffan I came up with the idea. The only thing that comes to mind is using Diophantine equations for the area.

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Good idea. Searching the OIES for "squares grid number fill" give 3 pages of results. Upon skimming through the results there was no such formula.

Comment: I would suggest computing some of the terms and looking for a sequence using the terms, instead of words-

Comment: https://oeis.org/A045846

Comment: @MarcusStuhr We have a winner :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be such a sequence in OIES:
 https://oeis.org/A045846